Help with Real Spherical Harmonics
I am trying to code a 3D representation of the position wavefunction probability of the Hydrogen atom.
I am having issues with the angular terms of the equation, which is represented as the real part of a spherical harmonic function.
The equation is:

And the Associated Legendre function is: 
I do the corresponding derivative (d/d_theta of cos(theta) of the function) for modes l=0 to l=3 through these tabulated equations: 
The final term: e^(i * m * phi) I represent with: sin(|m| * phi) if m < 0 and cos(m * phi) if m > 0.
After converting to cartesian coordinates, I end up with a 3D visual that looks like this: 
The x-z axis is actually quite good, as it matches what is expected from 2D cross-sections I found online: 
However, there is a discontinuity in the y-axis which should not be there.
By the way, theta ranges from 0-2pi and phi ranges from 0-pi. r is a constant in this case.
Is there anywhere in the math which I did incorrectly?

Please proofread and edit.

@Aruralreader What do you mean by this?

The representation of $e^{im\varphi}$ looks not very natural, because $e^{im\varphi}=\cos (m\varphi)+i\sin (m\varphi)$.

@AlexRavsky so you're saying the price wise I've been using is possibly incorrect and instead I should do Re(cos(m*phi) + i * sin(m * phi))?

Representation of the real part of spherical harmonics seems strange only for $m<0$. Both $m$ and $\phi$ are real, so $\mathrm{Re}(e^{im\phi}) = \cos(m\phi)$. Though, you used $m=1$ in your visual, so this couldn't have caused the problem.
The problem arises from your conventions for $\theta$ and $\phi$. As stated in the question, you took $\theta$ as polar angle (ranging from 0 to $2\pi$) and $\phi$ as azimuthal angle (ranging from 0 to $\pi$). In physics, the convention is: $\phi$ for polar angle and $\theta$ for azimuthal angle. This convention is also used in the equations (see Griffiths "Introduction to Quantum Mechanics" for comparison). Changing to the correct variables should eliminate the discontinuity.

This is the most helpful answer given so I awarded this the bounty. To help others in the future: the theta and phi variables are not switched up. I needed to change the range for the phi (azimuthal angle) to be 0 to 2pi just as theta (polar angle) is. This answer was the most helpful because indeed Re(imphi) is cos(|m| * phi) no matter the sign assuming the variables are real. The discontinuity is gone and simulates all states for the hydrogen atom. Thank you.
